# Why does os.environ.get('CUDA_HOME') return None when executing python with sudo?

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.8 under Anaconda3 on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine, and I am trying to use cuda toolkit 11.2. I have set "CUDA_HOME" properly such that both `echo $CUDA_HOME` and `sudo echo $CUDA_HOME` can return the correct CUDA_HOME value. My python script looks something like this:

```
import os
print(os.environ.get('CUDA_HOME'))
```

When I execute `python myscript.py`, the output is fine. However, when I use `sudo python myscript.py`, the result is None. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: When you do `sudo echo $CUDA_HOME`, the variable is being expanded in the original shell, not the shell run by `sudo`. Try `sudo bash -c 'echo $CUDA_HOME'` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the response, and you are right! Using your command does not seem to return anything. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Because `sudo` clears most environment variables.